# Vanilla JS : appendChild not working but innerHTML does [simple example]

Tags: javascript

In my example code innerHTML is working perfectly but not appendChild.  Can anyone explain why?

```js
function framework(selector) {
    if (window === this) { return new framework(selector); }

    if (selector === 'document') { this.element = [document]; }
    else if (selector === 'window') { this.element = [window]; }
    else if (selector) { this.element = document.querySelectorAll(selector); }

    return this;
};
framework.prototype.append = function(node){
    if (this.element[0]){ this.element[0].appendChild = node; }
    return this;
};
framework.prototype.html = function(node){
    if (this.element[0]){ this.element[0].innerHTML = node; }
    return this;
};


var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'test append';
framework("#example1").append(div);
framework("#example2").html('test html');
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
<div id="example2"></div>
```

Comment: It should be `appendChild(node)`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights : Oh man, thank you so much.  I'm not gonna tell you how long I wasted on this.  If you want to submit an answer I will mark you correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendChild` is a method whereas `innerHtml` is a property. So, as with all methods, the syntax is `appendChild(node)`.

Answer (score 1):

appendChild should take an argument. This should work:

```
  function framework(selector) {
        if (window === this) { return new framework(selector); }
    
        if (selector === 'document') { this.element = [document]; }
        else if (selector === 'window') { this.element = [window]; }
        else if (selector) { this.element = document.querySelectorAll(selector); }
    
        return this;
    };
    framework.prototype.append = function(node){
        if (this.element[0]){ this.element[0].appendChild(node); }
        return this;
    };
    framework.prototype.html = function(node){
        if (this.element[0]){ this.element[0].innerHTML(node); }
        return this;
    };
    
    
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'test append';
    framework("#example1").append(div);
    framework("#example2").html('test html');
```